# Is there a Source Control out there for .Net and iPhone development?

Tags: .net, iphone, version-control

I mainly do .Net development but have just bought an Apple Mac Book Pro and am wanting to do some iPhone Development as well. Is there a particular Source Control Software out there which  will handle integration with both Visual Studio and iPhone develeopment (Titanium/XCode) ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subversion has client integration available on both Visual Studio and XCode.

XCode - http://developer.apple.com/tools/subversionxcode.html
AnkhSVN (plugin for VS) - http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

You might also want to consider Git - more command line required, but it is also cross platform.

Honestly, I'd take the approach of leaving source control integration out of the IDE. As some of the commentors have mentioned - there are SVN clients that don't integrate but work wonderfully.

TortoiseSVN - http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ is just awesome Explorer-level integration for Windows.  I know that they are working on a Git client as well.

Comment: Unless things have changed recently, I haven't found much good git support on Windows (although things look pretty sharp on Mac and Linux).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using Xcode's svn support.  Just use svn from the command line.

Comment: Versions is an excellent product too instead of the XCode support

Answer (score 2):

Git is nice because it doesn't require a server.  And you can push it to a "master" on a remote drive, or a hosted solution like github, etc.

[GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/) is an excellent frontend on OSX.  I am sure there are integrations into XCode but I use mostly Komodo on OSX, so I needed something that was seperate.

[GitExtensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) has been working pretty decently for me integrating into VS2008.

Comment: This answer I feel is really the best, since I think developers should bite the bullet now in moving on to a distributed VCS like git - and you provided good ways to make that happen on both the Mac and Windows side for someone who does not necessarily wish to use the command line all the time for git management.

Comment: This is fantastic news - I'm looking to learn Git myself and while I'm not personally scared of the command line it's nice to know I won't have to always use it. +1 for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion will work. Xcode supports it natively, and there are Visual Studio add-ons for it as well.

Answer (score 1):

XCode supports Subversion, CVS, and Perforce. I haven't used Perforce but I can say that the CVS support is awful. The Subversion support is very good but it doesn't have enough features to make it great for anything beyond day-to-day use. So prepare to do more advanced stuff (like merging branches) from the command line.

A bonus is that every Mac has a SVN server built-in, so it makes it an even more attractive option.

Answer (score 0):

subversion is an excellent choice